# Using Lambda event for config dict

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a config dict as part of my python script that i'm converting into a lambda function, and am having a hard time getting one of the events to properly work in an endpoint URL.

```
config = dict(
        scope       = ["Mail.ReadWrite"], 
        username    = event['username'], 
        cache_file  = "token.cache", 
        date_range  = event['date_range'], 
        endpoint    = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$expand=attachments&$search="hasAttachments:true AND received:{event['date_range']}"'       
)
```

When trying to run with this endpoint, I get a syntax error:

```
"Syntax error in module 'xxx': f-string: unmatched.
```

I don't believe there's an issue with the format of the data coming from the event, because when I hard code the date in the endpoint it works fine along with the other event data coming in.

What is the correct format to have the endpoint to accept the date range presented in the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping quotations, something like this:

```
f"""https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$expand=attachments&$search="hasAttachments:true AND received:{event['date_range']}"\""""
```

Unless I'm mistaken, your error is nothing specific to lambda, just matching quotations

Comment: I just made this update and now its capturing the event data properly, but the API doesn't like the format the endpoint is using:
"errorMessage": "No connection adapters were found for '\"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$expand=attachments&$search=\"hasAttachments:true AND received:09/05/2022\"\"'",
  "errorType": "InvalidSchema"

Comment: `f'''https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$expand=attachments&$search="hasAttachments:true AND received:{event['date_range']}"'''`
this is what I ended up using to get the formatting to work with ms graphs api.